# IPython completion on @property

Tags: ipython, code-completion

I have a class with `@property` called `prop`. If a make an instance `bar` of the class and write `bar.prop.` in IPython and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> then code completion doesn't work.

On the other hand when I put variable `var` in the class and write `bar.var.` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> then code completion works.

Can I make code completion work with `@property` (I would like IPython to evaluate my property, get result and use it for suggestions)?

---

Here's the code:

```py
class Foo:
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")

class Bar:
    var = Foo()

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return Foo()

bar = Bar()
```

And `bar.var.` with <kbd>Tab</kbd> works, `bar.prop.` doesn't work with <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: This was asked recently.  The `ipython` tab does not evaluate the code.

Comment: Similar recent questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54944533/autocomplete-for-jupyter-notebook-and-ipython-console-for-classes-with-propert, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039499/autocomplete-with-encapsulation-of-property-decorator

Comment: Ok, so it seems I have to use `ipython.set_hook('complete_command', ...)` and create my own completer (I have to use `set_hook` because `set_custom_completer` seems broken according to https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11272).