# IPython Autocomplete: Accesses Subclass properties via a @property decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, properties, ipython

## Introduction

Image you want to describe a combustion process

In order to sort elements, I created

- classes for the describing the substance (eq. class Fuel)
- class which describes the combustion (eq. class combustion)
- `main.py` to run an example

## Python Files

**`properties.py`**

```py
class SolidProp:

    def __init__(self,ua):
        self._ultimate = Ultimate(ua)

    @property
    def ultimate(self):
        return self._ultimate

class Ultimate:

    def __init__(self,ua: dict):
        self._comp = ua

    @property
    def comp(self):
        return self._comp
```

**`combustion.py`**

```py
from properties import *

class Combustion:

    def __init__(self,ultimate):

        self.fuel = SolidProp(ua=ultimate)
```

**`main.py`**

```py
from combustion import *

burner = Combustion({'CH4':0.75, 'C2H4':0.25})
```

## Problem Description

### ipython console

In the ipython console (in bash) the following is not recognized **automatically** (but it can be called):

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 29 2018, 06:19:36) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: run 'main.py'

In [2]: burner.fuel.ultimate.comp
Out[2]: {'CH4': 0.75, 'C2H4': 0.25}
```

This has something to do that `*.ultimate` is defined via a decorator in `properties.py` (see `@property`) but I would like to be able to get `*.ultimate.comp` autocompleted in the ipython console, so people can work with it intuitively.

**Example**

- `burner.fuel.ultimate` is recognized
- `burner.fuel.ultimate.comp` is **NOT** recognized

I can not see any methods or properties beyond `burner.fuel.ultimate` in the ipython console. This makes it not intuitively for people to work with it when they do not know those methods exist.

*Remark:* ipython console of IDE pycharm works fine!?

### python console

Running it in the python console:

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 29 2018, 06:19:36) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exec(open("main.py").read())
>>> burner.fuel.ultimate.comp
{'CH4': 0.75, 'C2H4': 0.25}
```

Works fine. But why not in the ipython console from a terminal?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What does "not recognized automatically" mean? How does the result you get differ from what you expect?

Comment: See the __Eq.__ part.

Comment: Well, you still didn't explain what you mean by "recognized", but never mind. What's the point of the property? Why don't you just do `self.ultimate = Ultimate(s)` in the init?

Comment: Seems like it is about autocompletion.

Comment: @Sanyash: yes it is about autocomplete (sometimes it is hard to find the right words)

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: I want to run it through the decorator, because I want to implement some test routines there AND there are more fuels (Solids,LightLiquids,HeavyLiquids,Gas) each should have there unique `@property` definition.

Comment: I found those entries: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039499/autocomplete-with-encapsulation-of-property-decorator),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54944533/autocomplete-for-jupyter-notebook-and-ipython-console-for-classes-with-propert) which address the problem and it is an ongoing issue for the ipython developers see [issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11653)

Comment: Update to IPython 7.5.0 no change at this end.